# WordPress how to create templates and url in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I know how to create a single page and archive page but now I am trying to move everything into a custom plugin. So far I created my custom post type, 'location' and I created my files

```
/templates/archive-location.php
/templates/single-location.php
```

How can I get mysite.com/locations to read my archive-location.php all within my custom plugin.

***Update****
I was able to get my single page to work. Now how do I make it so this can be included in  any site? For instance I don't know their layout, should I include header and footer?

I need it so if I remove my plugin, mysite.com/locations doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for dynamically create custom templates during custom plugin is activated.

suppose i want to create two page first and second and i would like to assign custom templates to it.

Put below the code in your custom plugin's main file like index file of your custom plugin.

```
/* Runs when plugin is activated */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'news_plugin_install'); 

/* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'news_plugin_remove' );

function news_plugin_install() {
    $newsGagPages = array(
                        'First Page',
                        'Second Page'
                        );

    foreach ($newsGagPages as  $postTitle) {
        $my_post = array(
                    'post_title'    =>$postTitle,
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'post_author'   => 1,
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status'=>'publish');

         if(!get_page_by_title($postTitle))
         {
             $pageID = wp_insert_post($my_post,true);
         }

         if($postTitle =="First Page" ){
            add_post_meta( $pageID, '_wp_page_template', 'template-first.php' );
         }

         if($postTitle =="Second Page" ){
            add_post_meta( $pageID, '_wp_page_template', 'template-second.php' );
         }

    }
}



class PageTemplater {
    /* A Unique Identifier */
     protected $plugin_slug;

        /**
         * A reference to an instance of this class.
         */

        private static $instance;

        /**
         * The array of templates that this plugin tracks.
         */
        protected $templates;

        /**
         * Returns an instance of this class.
         */

        public static function get_instance() {

                if( null == self::$instance ) {
                        self::$instance = new PageTemplater();
                } 

                return self::$instance;

        } 

        /**
         * Initializes the plugin by setting filters and administration functions.
         */
        private function __construct() {

                $this->templates = array();

                // Add a filter to the attributes metabox to inject template into the cache.
            add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args',array( $this, 'register_project_templates' )
        );

        // Add a filter to the save post to inject out template into the page cache

            add_filter('wp_insert_post_data',array( $this, 'register_project_templates' )
        );

        // Add a filter to the template include to determine if the page has our 
        // template assigned and return it's path

            add_filter('template_include',array( $this, 'view_project_template')
        );

        // Add your templates to this array.
            $this->templates = array(
                                        'template-first.php'     => 'First',
                                        'template-second'=>'Second ',                                       
                                    );
        }

        /**
         * Adds our template to the pages cache in order to trick WordPress
         * into thinking the template file exists where it doens't really exist.
         *
         */

        public function register_project_templates( $atts ) {

                // Create the key used for the themes cache
                $cache_key = 'page_templates-' . md5( get_theme_root() . '/' . get_stylesheet() );

                // Retrieve the cache list. 
        // If it doesn't exist, or it's empty prepare an array
                $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
                if ( empty( $templates ) ) {
                        $templates = array();
                } 

                // New cache, therefore remove the old one
                wp_cache_delete( $cache_key , 'themes');

                // Now add our template to the list of templates by merging our templates
                // with the existing templates array from the cache.
                $templates = array_merge( $templates, $this->templates );

                // Add the modified cache to allow WordPress to pick it up for listing
                // available templates
                wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $templates, 'themes', 1800 );

                return $atts;
        } 

        /**
         * Checks if the template is assigned to the page
         */
        public function view_project_template( $template ) {

                global $post;

                if (!isset($this->templates[get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true)] ) ) {
                            return $template;
                }

                $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
                // Just to be safe, we check if the file exist first
                if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                        return $file;
                }else {
                    echo $file;
                }
                return $template;
        }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'PageTemplater', 'get_instance' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up using a shortcode.